# Как установить библиотеку Python

Tags: python, pip

Всем добрый день. Возникла проблема при установке библиотеки **pip install editdistance**. Попытался установить в PyCharm, на что вылезает ошибка:

```
Collecting editdistance
  Using cached editdistance-0.5.3.tar.gz (27 kB)
Could not build wheels for editdistance, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: editdistance
    Running setup.py install for editdistance: started
    Running setup.py install for editdistance: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\iljal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\editdistance\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\iljal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\editdistance\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gr3zn29q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\editdistance'
         cwd: C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\editdistance\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\editdistance
    copying editdistance\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\editdistance
    copying editdistance\_editdistance.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\editdistance
    copying editdistance\def.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\editdistance
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'editdistance.bycython' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\iljal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\editdistance\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\iljal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\editdistance\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gr3zn29q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\editdistance' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Питон новейший, 3.8.3, в чем проблема не понимаю. Подскажите как исправить. Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так в ошибке же написано `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required`. Даже ссылка дана на скачивание.

Comment: а зачем мне это скачивать? То есть библиотека без этого не робит?

Comment: Разработчик не предоставил скомпилированную версию для Python 3.8, а значит нужно компилировать из исходников самостоятельно. Для того и скачивать.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Или попробуйте поставить cmake. Он куда легче. Я его ставил для решения подобной проблемы с другими либами, но вот попробовал и editdistance установился.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!